# Return all the indexes of a particular substring

Tags: string, scala, indexof

Is there a Scala library API method (and if not, an idiomatic way) to obtain a list of all the indexes for a substring (target) within a larger string (source)? I have tried to look through the ScalaDoc, but was not able to find anything obvious. There are SO many methods doing so many useful things, I am guessing I am just not submitting the right search terms.

For example, if I have a source string of "name:Yo,name:Jim,name:name,name:bozo" and I use a target string of "name:", I would like to get back a List[Int] of List(0, 8, 17, 27).

Here's my quick hack to resolve the problem:

```
def indexesOf(source: String, target: String, index: Int = 0, withinOverlaps: Boolean = false): List[Int] = {
    def recursive(index: Int, accumulator: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
      if (!(index < source.size)) accumulator
      else {
        val position = source.indexOf(target, index)
        if (position == -1) accumulator
        else {
          recursive(position + (if (withinOverlaps) 1 else target.size), position :: accumulator)
        }
      }
    }

    if (target.size <= source.size) {
      if (!source.equals(target)) {
        recursive(0, Nil).reverse
      }
      else List(0)
    }
    else Nil
  }
```

Any guidance you can give me replacing this with a proper standard library entry point would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 2019/Jun/16:**

Further code tightening:

```
  def indexesOf(source: String, target: String, index: Int = 0, withinOverlaps: Boolean = false): List[Int] = {
    def recursive(indexTarget: Int = index, accumulator: List[Int] = Nil): List[Int] = {
      val position = source.indexOf(target, indexTarget)
      if (position == -1)
        accumulator
      else
        recursive(position + (if (withinOverlaps) 1 else target.size), position :: accumulator)
    }
    recursive().reverse
  }
```

**UPDATE 2014/Jul/22:**

Inspired by Siddhartha Dutta's answer, I tighted up my code. It now looks like this:

```
  def indexesOf(source: String, target: String, index: Int = 0, withinOverlaps: Boolean = false): List[Int] = {
    @tailrec def recursive(indexTarget: Int, accumulator: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
      val position = source.indexOf(target, indexTarget)
      if (position == -1) accumulator
      else
        recursive(position + (if (withinOverlaps) 1 else target.size), position :: accumulator)
    }
    recursive(index, Nil).reverse
  }
```

Additionally, if I have a source string of "aaaaaaaa" and I use a target string of "aa", I would like by default to get back a List[Int] of List(0, 2, 4, 6) which skips a search starting inside of a found substring. The default can be overridden by passing "true" for the withinOverlaps parameter which in the "aaaaaaaa"/"aa" case would return List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).

Comment: No, there is not "a [standard] method". Also, since this is working code, it *might* be more fitting for code-review.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium Any way you could BSD License that method so the boss man doesn't get mad at me if I copy/adapt it? :)

Comment: @ericpeters It's my understanding that any code snippets posted here on StackOverflow may be assumed to essentially be public domain; i.e. unencumbered by any license constraints limiting your ability to cut/paste/modify/customize the snippet to whatever context you need.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium It's a funny gray area, they don't technically become MIT-ish with attribution until March (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange)

Comment: You should update the answer to use a Vector (and append instead of prepend) instead of a List to avoid the extra .reverse at the end.  Probably would be helpful to return a type IndexedSeq[Int] as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am always inclined to reach into the bag of regex tricks with problems like this one.  I wouldn't say it is *proper*, but it's a hell of a lot less code. :)

```
val r = "\\Qname\\E".r
val ex = "name:Yo,name:Jim,name:name,name:bozo"

val is = r.findAllMatchIn(ex).map(_.start).toList
```

The quotes `\\Q` and `\\E` aren't necessary for this case, but if the string you're looking for has any special characters, then it will be.

Comment: Very nice. I spent less than two minutes evaluating the regex approach before whipping up my code Scala. It's nice to have more than one way to skin the string search cat.

Comment: BTW, you can also change the first line to """\Qname\E""".r if you want to use the pure regex (as an unescaped copy/paste from some other source). The triple quotes option in Scala is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

A small code to get all the indexes
call the below method as getAllIndexes(source, target)

```
def getAllIndexes(source: String, target: String, index: Int = 0): List[Int] = {
        val targetIndex = source.indexOf(target, index)
        if(targetIndex != -1)
          List(targetIndex) ++ getAllIndexes(source, target, targetIndex+1)
        else
          List()
      }
```

Comment: This appears to return the list in reverse order, i.e. List(27, 17, 8, 0), right? Additionally, you can optimize the two if pathways. The first replacing "List(targetIndex) ++ get..." with "targetIndex :: get...". And the second replacing "List()" with "Nil".

Comment: No the method returns the list in ascending order as per indexes i.e., List(0,8,17,27). The optimizations are correct.

Comment: I just tried your call and after adding the @tailrec annotation, I am getting a compiler error stating it is not tail recursive (with either ++ or ::). However, your smaller code inspired me, so I provided an update to show my code tightened up. I also added another test case (the "aaaaaaaa", "aa" example) to show the benefit of the optional withinOverlaps parameter.

Comment: Yes the method is not tail recursive as it is first calling itself then adding the result.

Comment: Ah. I have a string where I'm getting hundreds to thousands of hits back and cannot afford possibly blowing the call stack.